# How to keep the dock on top of all windows? (I don't want windows to be smaller because of Dock)

Tags: macos, dock, window-manager

How to keep the dock on top of all windows? (I don't want windows to be smaller because of the dock when the dock is visible)

I don't want to hide the dock. I don't want to place it to the left or right of the screen.

I don't want to move the cursor to the dock to make it visible. I want the dock to be visible allways.

I want windows to act as if the dock is hidden (maximize their size) BUT I want the dock to be on top of all windows. Preferably, including full screen windows.

How can we make this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What setting causes OS X to let you resize windows behind the dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/what-setting-causes-os-x-to-let-you-resize-windows-behind-the-dock)

Comment: No, sorry, it doesn't.

Comment: @user3722246 Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). Please note also we have expectations around behaviour, so I've edited your last comment as some may find that offensive. Please refer to [Expected Behaviour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for more info.